# Portfolio optimization with Portfolio CVaR Constraint

Tags: portfolio, portfolio-optimization, cvar

I wanted to optimize a portfolio based on a portfolio-wide CVaR constraint (i.e. $CVaR_p \leq 0.08$). Unfortunately, I only find solution that minimizes the entire CVaR of the Portfolio.
[image: Exhibit Gordon 2007]

Do you mind telling me if I need to add a restriction or how to change the utility function?

Here, you find the initial data and optimization [Link](http://www.leippold.ch/matlab.html)

### Edit

I removed some stupid elements. I will give a full answer once I finished the semester at the university.

### Links

Paper [Portfolio Optimization with Conditional Value-at-Risk Objective and Constraints](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~krokhmal/pdf/cvar.pdf)

Comment: Check out "Portfolio Optimization with Conditional Value-at-Risk Objective and Constraints" by Krokhmal, Palmquist, and Uryasev

Comment: @John: I think they added a (C)VaR Constraint on the asset side. I want to minimize the variance of the portfolio and also force the portfolio not to extend a certain CVaR limit. Do you know how to implement such a optimizer/solver?

Comment: That paper comes very close to solving your issue. They show how to constrain the CVaR of a portfolio to an amount while maximizing return. All you have to do is replace the objective with minimizing variance. Alternately, after setting it up that way, you could replace the linearization with Alexander et al's approach in "Minimizing CVaR and VaR for a portfolio of derivatives", though you couldn't use an LP anymore.

Comment: @John: I followed the first hint and used LP to minimize variance and added a CVaR constraint. I didn't have that much success. Do you mind having a look at my "example"?

Comment: I would follow the progression of first getting the minimize CVaR to work, then max return given CVaR, then min variance given CVaR. The problem here is that you're not using Rockafellar & Urysev's approach at all. The weighted average CVaR of individual assets is not the CVaR of the portfolio. This doesn't work for variance, so it wouldn't work for CVaR. Read Rockafellar and Urysev's Optimization of Conditional Value at Risk. Both of the authors have presentations on their websites that explain it better. Check those out.

Comment: @Markus: In my opinion if you have to specify CVaR for each asset then the portfolio CVaR will be sub-optimal, because it forgoes diversification. CVaR for a portfolio with normally distributed returns optimization has an analytic solution. For non-normal portfolio, you could numerically simulate the returns via FHS or MC or parametric VaR and optimize. To use LP, returns have to be function of asset. The link you are following, which you did not mention, assume efficient VaR for the assets exist. Asset VaR are not sub-additive, so I would be quite careful with that.

Comment: @Markus: I don't understand the first two sentences of the question: don't they refer to the same constraint, namely the CVaR of the portfolio?

Comment: @Felix: There is a small difference: I want to add CVaR as a constraint. But, I only found a solution that uses CVaR as the objective. (I could not enter the optimization properly on stackexchange.)

Comment: @Markus: mean variance with a CVaR constraint? perhaps Monte Carlo optimization is a useful approach here. Additional constraints can be included quite easily, by rejecting trial moves which violate them.

Comment: @Felix: I had a pretty interessting conversation with a colleague today and he pointed out that Dr. Uryasev et al. worte a paper in 2000. I will wirte the solution once I find some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a linear solver with a CVaR-Constraint is time-consuming. "[Portfolio Safeguard](http://www.aorda.com)" of "American Optimal Decision Inc." is optimized for such kind of problems.

In order to get it work, you must add the following elements:

Data

- matrix_scenarios (a matrix of all your returns)
- matrix_returns (a vector containing the expected returns)

Function

- CVaR (cvar_risk)
- linear (linear)
- standard deviation (st_risk)

Problem

- variance as objective
- CVaR as constraint
- budget as constraint
- Box variables

Optimization

- you can run the optimization by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>

Later I will illustrate the process.